# Path.GetExtension does not give correct file extension

Tags: c#

I am using Path.GetExtension(filename) to get extension of filename.

Recently my code got input like `Home_FIRSTNAME@LASTNAME_POI Name_match (03.2.20)`. It is giving extension as `.20)`. I was expecting it should give me blank(""), since input does not have any extension. It works fine for other scenarios like `abc.pdf`, but not for this one.

Comment: `Home_FIRSTNAME@LASTNAME_POI Name_match (03.2.20)` isn't a proper file name either

Comment: If it is not proper filename, dont you think Path.GetFileExtension should return null or empty , instead of returning wrong extension ?

Comment: `.20)` _is_ the extension of that file name.

Answer (score 3):

`Path.GetExtension` works in the following way:

> This method obtains the extension of path by searching path for a
>   period (.), starting with the last character in path and continuing
>   toward the first character. If a period is found before a
>   DirectorySeparatorChar or AltDirectorySeparatorChar character, the
>   returned string contains the period and the characters after it;
>   otherwise, String.Empty is returned.

It returns the last period found and all characters following this.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getextension?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 1):

---

> *"the input does not have any extension."*

---

**Wrong.** `.20)` is the extension.

It might not have a meaningful file type, but file extension and file type are not related. File names, including the extensions, are just strings as far as windows is concerned. You could change a file named `abc.docx` to be `abc.zip`, and you haven't really changed the file.

Answer (score 0):

That's expected behavior as already posted in another answer. As an alternative you can try something like below

```
   var extension = Path.GetExtension("Home_FIRSTNAME@LASTNAME_POI Name_match (03.2.20)");
   extension = extension.ToArray().All(x => Char.IsLetter(x)) ? extension : string.Empty;
```